# Test for time part existence in DATE data type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have one field in my database of type DATE. I want to store date and time or only date  in.
The problem is how to test that my DATE column contain date and time or just a date.

> v_date DATE; 
>   v_date := to_date('01-01-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY'); 
>   v_text := to_char(v_date, 'HH24:Mi');

to_char('HH24:Mi') for only date returns '00:00', not null.
Is there any way to test that Date column contains date and time or only date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DATE datatype allways contain Date **and** Time.

And it's just a bad ideea to store time and date separate. You can just test against your DATE column whatever you want about Time part.

For example, to test if the column is at midnight you can use:

```
if trunc(your_column) = your_column 
then blabla;
end if;
```

and use `<>` instead of `=` for the otherwise.

Comment: DATE allways contain the time part. If you need to store only Date part, just write trunc(column_name). And read trunc(column_name). The time will be 00:00. And you'll benefit from DATE datatype speed.